# SparkSQL - Extract multiple regex matches (using SQL only)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset of SQL queries in raw text and another with a regular expression of all the possible table names:

```
# queries
+-----+----------------------------------------------+
| id  | query                                        |                  
+-----+----------------------------------------------+
| 1   | select * from table_a, table_b               |
| 2   | select * from table_c join table_d...        |
+-----+----------------------------------------------+

# regexp
'table_a|table_b|table_c|table_d'
```

And I wanted the following result:

```
# expected result
+-----+----------------------------------------------+
| id  | tables                                       |                  
+-----+----------------------------------------------+
| 1   | [table_a, table_b]                           |
| 2   | [table_c, table_d]                           |
+-----+----------------------------------------------+
```

But using the following SQL in Spark, all I get is the first match...

```
select
  id,
  regexp_extract(query, 'table_a|table_b|table_c|table_d') as tables
from queries

# actual result
+-----+----------------------------------------------+
| id  | tables                                       |                  
+-----+----------------------------------------------+
| 1   |  table_a                                     |
| 2   |  table_c                                     |
+-----+----------------------------------------------+
```

Is there any way to do this **using only Spark SQL**? This is the function I am using [https://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-nightly/spark-master-docs/latest/api/sql/#regexp_extract](https://people.apache.org/%7Epwendell/spark-nightly/spark-master-docs/latest/api/sql/#regexp_extract)

**EDIT**

I would also accept a solution that returned the following:

```
# alternative solution
+-----+----------------------------------------------+
| id  | tables                                       |                  
+-----+----------------------------------------------+
| 1   | table_a                                      |
| 1   | table_b                                      |
| 2   | table_c                                      |
| 2   | table_d                                      |
+-----+----------------------------------------------+
```

**SOLUTION**

@chlebek solved this below. I reformatted his SQL using CTEs for better readability:

```sql
with
split_queries as (
  select 
    id, 
    explode(split(query, ' ')) as col
  from queries
),
extracted_tables as (
  select 
    id, 
    regexp_extract(col, 'table_a|table_b|table_c|table_d', 0) as rx
  from split_queries
)
select
  id,
  collect_set(rx) as tables
from extracted_tables
where rx != ''
group by id
```

Bear in mind that the `split(query, ' ')` part of the query will split your SQL only by spaces. If you have other things such as tabs, line breaks, comments, etc., you should deal with these before or when splitting.

Comment: Maybe a udf? What language are you using?

Comment: @ernest_k Python, a UDF would work well, but unfortunately I can't use it in my current scenario, it has to be SQL only...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only a few values to check you can achieve it using `contains` function instead of regexp:

```
val names = Seq("table_a","table_b","table_c","table_d")
def c(col: Column) = names.map(n => when(col.contains(n),n).otherwise(""))
df.select('id,array_remove(array(c('query):_*),"").as("result")).show(false)
```

but using regexp it will looks like below (Spark SQL API):

```
df.select('id,explode(split('query," ")))
.select('id,regexp_extract('col,"table_a|table_b|table_c|table_d",0).as("rx"))
.filter('rx=!="")
.groupBy('id)
.agg(collect_list('rx))
```

and it could be translated to below **SQL query**:

```
select id, collect_list(rx) from
    (select id, regexp_extract(col,'table_a|table_b|table_c|table_d',0) as rx from
        (select id, explode(split(query,' ')) as col from df) q1
    ) q2
where rx != '' group by id
```

so output will be:

```
+---+------------------+
| id|  collect_list(rx)|
+---+------------------+
|  1|[table_a, table_b]|
|  2|[table_c, table_d]|
+---+------------------+
```

Comment: I do have many values, but the biggest issue is that I need the solution to be in SQL only, it's a limitation I have...

Comment: works, thanks! I will edit my question with your response, formatted using CTEs for better readability (IMO)

Answer (score 0):

You can use another SQL function available in Spark called collect_list https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/functions.html#collect_list. You can find another sample https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/arraytype-columns/

Basically, applying to your code it should be

```
val df = spark.sql("select 1 id, 'select * from table_a, table_b' query" )
val df1 = spark.sql("select 2 id, 'select * from table_c join table_d' query" )

val df3 = df.union(df1)

df3.createOrReplaceTempView("tabla")

   spark.sql("""
select id, collect_list(tables) from (
        select id, explode(split(query, ' ')) as tables
        from tabla)
where tables like 'table%' group by id""").show
```

The output will be

```
+---+--------------------+
| id|collect_list(tables)|
+---+--------------------+
|  1| [table_a,, table_b]|
|  2|  [table_c, table_d]|
+---+--------------------+
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Did you able to get it working? I tried spark-2.4.5 it is still resulting **`[table_a]`** instead of **`[table_a,table_b]`**!

Comment: I have changed the answer to be more regular expression agnostic, so it doesn't matter how many tables you have in your field query. It will collect all of them in an array. Sorry on the my previous answer I thought that your question was slightly different

Answer (score 0):

As you are using spark-sql, you can use sql parser & it will do job for you.

```
def getTables(query: String): Seq[String] = {
  val logicalPlan = spark.sessionState.sqlParser.parsePlan(query)
  import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnresolvedRelation
  logicalPlan.collect { case r: UnresolvedRelation => r.tableName }
}

val query = "select * from table_1 as a left join table_2 as b on 
a.id=b.id"
scala> getTables(query).foreach(println)
table_1
table_2
```

You can register 'getTables' as udf & use in query

Answer (score 0):

If you are on `spark>=2.4` then you can remove `exploding` and `collecting the same` operations by using higher order functions on array and without any subqueries-

### Load the test data

```scala
 val data =
      """
        |id  | query
        |1   | select * from table_a, table_b
        |2   | select * from table_c join table_d on table_c.id=table_d.id
      """.stripMargin
    val stringDS = data.split(System.lineSeparator())
      .map(_.split("\\|").map(_.replaceAll("""^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$""", "")).mkString(";"))
      .toSeq.toDS()
    val df = spark.read
      .option("sep", ";")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("nullValue", "null")
      .csv(stringDS)
    df.printSchema()
    df.show(false)

    /**
      * root
      * |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- query: string (nullable = true)
      *
      * +---+-----------------------------------------------------------+
      * |id |query                                                      |
      * +---+-----------------------------------------------------------+
      * |1  |select * from table_a, table_b                             |
      * |2  |select * from table_c join table_d on table_c.id=table_d.id|
      * +---+-----------------------------------------------------------+
      */
```

### Extract the tables from query

```scala
  // spark >= 2.4.0
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("queries")
    spark.sql(
      """
        |select id,
        |   array_distinct(
        |   FILTER(
        |     split(query, '\\.|=|\\s+|,'), x -> x rlike 'table_a|table_b|table_c|table_d'
        |     )
        |    )as tables
        |FROM
        |   queries
      """.stripMargin)
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +---+------------------+
      * |id |tables            |
      * +---+------------------+
      * |1  |[table_a, table_b]|
      * |2  |[table_c, table_d]|
      * +---+------------------+
      */
```